# error when django with rest-framework deployed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having error when trying to open url of Django Rest framework.
It was working fine locally, but when I deployed it on server, I am having following error. On server I have django 1.9.

```
Exception Value:    

'url' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'future'

Exception Location:     /home/maxo/django-trunk/django/template/base.py in parse, line 506

Error during template rendering

In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html, error at line 1

'url' is not a valid tag or filter in tag library 'future'
1   

      {% load url from future %}



2   {% load staticfiles %}
3   {% load rest_framework %}
4   <!DOCTYPE html>
5   <html>
6       <head>
7           {% block head %}
8   
9               {% block meta %}
10                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
11                  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
```

NOTE : When I removed following line:
{% load url from future %} from base.html 
Its working fine now, but then style of rest api is gone. Is there any other alternative to replace {% load url from future %}?

Comment: When I removed following line:
{% load url from future %} from base.html 
Its working fine now, but then style of rest api is gone. Is there any other alternative to replace {% load url from future %}?

Answer (score 4):

**In Django 1.9, `url` template tag was removed from the `future` template tag library.**

From [Django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9):

> `ssi` and `url` template tags will be removed from the `future` template tag
>   library (used during the 1.3/1.4 deprecation period).

So, now you can't load the `url` tag from the `future` library in Django 1.9. You can use the built-in `url` tag instead.

```
{% url 'some-url-name' %}
```

Comment: When I removed following line:
{% load url from future %} from base.html 
Its working fine now, but then style of rest api is gone. Is there any other alternative to replace {% load url from future %}?

Comment: You can use the default url tag instead. `{% url 'some-url-name'  %}`

Comment: so do I need replace 'some-url-name' with anything? as I need to replace {% load url from future %} with  something on base.html file which is in DJANGO rest Framwork folder

Comment: `some-url-name` can be a view function or a reverse url name. Lets say if your url has a `name=my_url_name` argument defined in the `urls.py` file, then you can just use`{% url 'my_url_name' %}`. In case of namespaced URL, you need to specify the fully qualified URL like  `{% url 'myapp:view_name' %}`

Answer (score 1):

you can fix that by installing a newer version of djangorestframework

```
pip install 'djangorestframework>=3.2.3'
```

i don't think it's a good idea to develop on a version of django and deploy on some other version, that'll most likely give you problems.
i'd work using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), and saving a `requirements.txt` file with the version of all the packages you're using. that way when you deploy you can run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and that'll install the same versions as you are using in your dev environment.

hope this helps.
salú